# Is it possible to hide a macro like BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(lvl)

Tags: c++, boost

I have used `boost.log` in one project for a while and it's a really great log lib. 
But to use a basic log like `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(lvl)` I need to include `boost/log/trivial.hpp` which will cause a lots of boost related stuff to be scoped.

Is there any way (like using a wrapper or alias) to "hide" `boost/log/trivial.hpp` and `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(lvl)` so I can be sure any other developer can only call the wrapped version of `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(lvl)`?

At the very beginning I thought `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(lvl)` was a simple stream object but then I found that it will be expanded as:

```
#define BOOST_LOG_STREAM_WITH_PARAMS_INTERNAL(logger, rec_var, params_seq)\
    for (::boost::log::record rec_var = (logger).open_record((BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(params_seq))); !!rec_var;)\
        ::boost::log::aux::make_record_pump((logger), rec_var).stream()
```

There is a for-loop here and I have no idea how to wrap it.

Comment: All of the things used by that macro uses (types, functions, etc) needs to be declared or (in the case of macros) `#defined`. Otherwise, any usage of the macro will not compile. If you really want to "hide" usage of the macro, write your own FUNCTION (not a macro) that accepts arguments of appropriate types, and uses the boost macro. Then declare that function in a separate header file, and define it in a separate compilation unit (aka source file). Unless other developers explicitly `#include` the boost header (which you can't prevent) they won't be able to use the macro directly.

Comment: @Peter Thx for helping and I'm trying to have a wrapper class with overriding operator<<.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a non-trivial task to replicate what that macro is doing. You need a macro too, but if you want to hide all the boost details in an implementation unit, then you need to replicate the method calls in some way.

Firstly you need a wrapper around `boost::log::record` and then a wrapper around `boost::log::record_pump<>` and finally methods to make your wrapper instances. The end result should look something like this:

```
namespace foo {
  enum severity {
    debug, info, warn, error;
  }

  struct record {
    // use pimpl to hide
  };

  struct record_pump {
    // use pimpl to hide
  };

  // This will call the trivial logger to create a record and then
  // wrap with your record
  record make_record(severity lvl);

  // This method will call the boost `boost::log::make_record_pump` method
  // with the trivial logger and wrap the resulting `record_pump<T>` by your wrapper
  record_pump make_record_pump(record& rec);  
}
```

Then declare a macro that looks like the boost macro - remember you'll need to expose the levels in your own enums

```
#define LOG(lvl) \
for (auto rec = foo::make_record(lvl); !!rec;) \
  foo::make_record_pump(rec).stream()
```

You'll need to implement the necessary bits of the `record` and `record_pump` interface.

Comment: Indeed it's not a ez task to do so, but I'm trying to have a wrapper class with overriding operator<< . Thx for helping